# Which algorithm is used to compute exponential functions the GNU C++ Standard Library?

Tags: c++, gnu, libstdc++, exponentiation

Please consider [std::exp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp) defined in the header [cmath](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) in C++ [numerics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric) library. Now, please consider an implementation of the C++ Standard Library, say [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/).

Considering **there are various algorithms** to compute the elementary functions, such as [arithmetic-geometric mean iteration algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3412) to compute the exponential function and three others shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Elementary_functions);

Could you please name the particular algorithm being used to compute the exponential function in [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/), if possible?

PS: I could not pinpoint either the correct tarballs containing the std::exp implementation or comprehend the relevant file contents, I'm afraid.

Comment: libstdc++ just forwards to the compiler intrinsic `__builtin_exp`, which will have a varying implementation by platform and compiler.

Comment: __builtin_exp is just a fancy name for ::exp, the C function declared in math.h. Gcc does not contain any implementation of exp, you want to look for it in your C library (e.g. glibc).

Comment: dug up the sources for you. See the updated answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't use any intricate algorithm at all. Note that `std::exp` is only defined for a very limited number of types: `float`, `double` and `long double` + any Integral type that is castable to `double`. That makes it not necessary to implement complicated maths.

Currently, it uses the builtin `__builtin_expf` as can be verified from the source code. This compiles to a call to `expf` on my machine which is a call into `libm` coming from `glibc`. Let's see what we find in their [source code](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html). When we search for `expf` we find that this internally calls `__ieee754_expf` which is a system-dependant implementation. Both i686 and x86_64 just include a `glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_expf.c` which finally gives us an implementation (reduced for brevity, the look [into the sources](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_expf.c.html)

It is basically a order 3 polynomial approximation for floats:

```
static inline uint32_t
top12 (float x)
{
  return asuint (x) >> 20;
}

float
__expf (float x)
{
  uint64_t ki, t;
  /* double_t for better performance on targets with FLT_EVAL_METHOD==2.  */
  double_t kd, xd, z, r, r2, y, s;

  xd = (double_t) x;
  // [...] skipping fast under/overflow handling

  /* x*N/Ln2 = k + r with r in [-1/2, 1/2] and int k.  */
  z = InvLn2N * xd;

  /* Round and convert z to int, the result is in [-150*N, 128*N] and
     ideally ties-to-even rule is used, otherwise the magnitude of r
     can be bigger which gives larger approximation error.  */
  kd = roundtoint (z);
  ki = converttoint (z);
  r = z - kd;

  /* exp(x) = 2^(k/N) * 2^(r/N) ~= s * (C0*r^3 + C1*r^2 + C2*r + 1) */
  t = T[ki % N];
  t += ki << (52 - EXP2F_TABLE_BITS);
  s = asdouble (t);
  z = C[0] * r + C[1];
  r2 = r * r;
  y = C[2] * r + 1;
  y = z * r2 + y;
  y = y * s;
  return (float) y;
}
```

Similarly, for 128-bit `long double`, it's an [order 7 approximation](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-128/e_expl.c.html#185) and for `double` they use [more complicated algorithm](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-128/e_expl.c.html#185) that I can't make sense of right now.

Comment: You are looking at x87 instructions, which are only remotely relevant for long double nowadays. If you look at asm, __builtin_expf becomes a call to expf (provided by the C library).

Comment: @MarcGlisse I've tried getting gcc to inline that call but didn't succeed.

Comment: Of course it didn't inline it. How often have you seen functions from external libraries inlined in your code?

Comment: I found this answer really helpful! Oddly enough, it looks like this is not the actual algorithm which is used in current *releases* of glibc. The source for version 2.26 (the most recent release, from Feb 1 2018) is different - see https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_expf.c;h=782072f213ca8ad5ef7aa63ae0276086ea6e04c7;hb=refs/heads/release/2.26/master . The source was recently modified (https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=72aa623345ada1276ed89dbc00fdff9639cb8eaf) but this change seems to have not made it through to release

Comment: I got my timelines wrong in the previous comment. Glibc version 2.26 is from Aug 2017 and has the old algorithm (different from that posted in this answer) but version 2.27 (from Feb 1 2018) uses the algorithm presented above. Still, if your glibc isn't super up-to-date, then the algorithm your machine uses is probably different.

Comment: the mathematical formula on which this is based is the [taylor series of exp(x)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Exponential_function)