# python square root using x**0.5 calculation required

Tags: python, math

I'm wondering how does calculation made in the python using the power (**) with 0.5 calculate the square root value.

So while doing `2**0.5` in python we are getting 1.4142135.

Does anyone knows how does calculation has been made in python. how can we do that math in written.

Comment: Are you asking for the mathematical or pythonic explanation for why 2^(1/2) is 1.4?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Comment: You want to know how `a**b`, or in mathematical notation `a^b`, is computed for non-integer exponents `b` like `0.5`? The basic idea (for all programming languages) is that `a^b = e^(b ln a)` where `e^x` is the exponential function with Euler number `e=2.71828...`, which has a simple Taylor series expansion: `e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + ...`. Based on that sophisticated optimizations are applied. See also these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724862, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960020

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, x<sup>1/2</sup> is √x (√2 is approximately 1.41).

Python calculates square roots using `2^(y*log2(x))`.

`y*log2(x)` and `2^x` are both instructions on the compiler for CPython.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is that x to the power of (1/2) is mathematically equivalent to the square root of x

Comment: Hi Michael M, Thanks for your valuable timing. I know that its  x(1/2). But like to know the math calculation behind python how its calculating. :)

Answer (score -1):

The ** operator in Python is equivalent to raising one value to the value of another.

So in your case. `2**0.5` is equivalent to 2^(1/2) which is in turn, equivalent to the square root of 2.