# e^x without math.h

Tags: c, math, numerical-methods

I'm trying to find e<sup>*x*</sup> without using math.h. My code gives wrong anwsers when *x* is bigger or lower than ~±20. I tried to change all double types to long double types, but it gave some trash on input.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double fabs1(double x) {
    if(x >= 0){
        return x;
    } else {
        return x*(-1);
    }
}

double powerex(double x) {
    double a = 1.0, e = a;
    for (int n = 1; fabs1(a) > 0.001; ++n) {
        a = a * x / n;
        e += a;
    }
    return e;
}

int main(){
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        double number;
        scanf("%lf", &number);
        double e = powerex(number);
        printf("%0.15g\n", e);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
8
0.0
1.0
-1.0
2.0
-2.0
100.0
-100.0
0.189376476361643
```

My output:

```
1
2.71825396825397
0.367857142857143
7.38899470899471
0.135379188712522
2.68811714181613e+043
-2.91375564689153e+025
1.20849374134639
```

Right output:

```
1
2.71828182845905
0.367879441171442
7.38905609893065
0.135335283236613
2.68811714181614e+43
3.72007597602084e-44
1.20849583696666
```

You can see that my answer for e<sup>−100</sup> is absolutely incorrect. Why does my code output this? What can I do to improve this algorithm?

Comment: Modify the code to print the values of `n` and `a` as it goes through the loop, then run it for the −100 case and see what the values look like. See how big they get. What resolution does the `double` format have? How accurately can the sums be represented when the numbers get that big? What size error should you expect?

Comment: Run with a debugger, or add intermediate prints in your calculating loop, and see when the value of `a` is starting to deviate from the expectation.

Comment: Could there be `int` overflow?

Comment: GCC has builtin functions `__builtin_expf` and `__builtin_expd` you can call, [as documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), but I guess your questions is really more about doing calculations yourself instead of avoiding a specific header file.  And those functions just seem to call the C library under the hood anyway, instead of doing something more direct.

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960020/with-which-algorithm-exponential-functions-are-computed-in-the-gnu-c-standard

Comment: Also interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984440/approximate-ex

Comment: It's just a limit of this kind of approximation. Try to inspect the values and their progression: https://godbolt.org/z/85T95nM3K

Comment: Here `for (int n = 1; fabs1(a) > 0.001; ++n) {`, you impose that the approximation is generally not better than 0.001

Comment: OP, take a look at asymptotic expansions for large (positive or negative) arguments. It's probably covered in "Handbook of Mathematical Functions" by Abramowitz and Stegun, which I think you can find on the web.

Comment: An absolute (and arbitrary) test like `fabs1(a) > 0.001` is always suspicious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `x` is negative, the sign of each term alternates.  This means each successive sum switches widely in value rather than increasing more gradually when a positive power is used.  This means that the loss in precision with successive terms has a large effect on the result.

To handle this, check the sign of `x` at the start.  If it is negative, switch the sign of `x` to perform the calculation, then when you reach the end of the loop invert the result.

Also, you can reduce the number of iterations by using the following counterintuitive condtion:

```
e != e + a
```

On its face, it appears that this should always be true.  However, the condition becomes false when the value of `a` is outside of the precision of the value of `e`, in which case adding `a` to `e` doesn't change the value of `e`.

```
double powerex(double x) {
    double a = 1.0, e = a;
    int invert = x<0;
    x = fabs1(x);
    for (int n = 1; e != e + a ; ++n) {
        a = a * x / n;
        e += a;
    }
    return invert ? 1/e : e;
}
```

We can optimize a bit more to remove one loop iteration by initializing `e` with 0 instead of `a`, and calculating the next term at the bottom of the loop instead of the top:

```
double powerex(double x) {
    double a = 1.0, e = 0;
    int invert = x<0;
    x = fabs1(x);
    for (int n = 1; e != e + a ; ++n) {
        e += a;
        a = a * x / n;
    }
    return invert ? 1/e : e;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For values of x above one or so, you may consider to handle the integer part separately and compute powers of e by squarings. (E.g. e^9 = ((e²)²)².e takes 4 multiplies)

Indeed, the general term of the Taylor development, x^n/n! only starts to decrease after n>x (you multiply each time by x/k), so the summation takes at least x terms. On another hand, e^n can be computed in at most 2lg(n) multiplies, which is more efficient and more accurate.

So I would advise

- to take the fractional part of x and use Taylor,
- when the integer part is positive, multiply by e raised to that power,
- when the integer part is zero, you are done,
- when the integer part is negative, divide by e raised to that power.

---

You can even spare more by considering quarters: in the worst case (x=1), Taylor requires 18 terms before the last one becomes negligible. If you consider subtracting from x the immediately inferior multiple of 1/4 (and compensate multiplying by precomputed powers of e), the number of terms drops to 12.

E.g. e^0.8 = e^(3/4+0.05) = 2.1170000166126747 . e^0.05

Comment: If you add constants, consider using `ln2`, then decompose `x=m*ln2+u`, `abs(u)<=0.5*ln2<0.35`, so that the result is `2^m*exp(u)`. Otherwise the idea would be to compute `y=exp(x/2^n)` and recover `exp(x)` be `n` squarings of `y`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: squarings of `exp(x/2^n)` won't work, due to the truncation errors.

Comment: But you propose to compute the bulk of the result from squarings of `e`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: yes, this is safe, not squarings from numbers like 1.000000001, If I am right.

Comment: The idea is of course to have `x/2^n` in some moderate range, `0.5 to 1` as example, so that the power series or polynomial approximation works reasonably fast and the squaring does not impact the accuracy too much. This method is indeed used in the math library of the `bc` multiprecision command-line tool, arguably with rising the working precision to account for the accuracy loss of the squaring "trick".